# How to get selected item when Mouse hover in my listview?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, listview, mousehover

How to get selected Item and SubItems When I drag over Listview Items.
 I tried this but didn't get the accurate solution. I got the solution on first mouse hover Selected item  only. when ever i keep on hover different Items it will not display the latest hover item

```
 private void lvThumbnail_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (lvThumbnail.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
            {
                txtCity.Text = lvThumbnail.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[1].Text;
                txtCurrency.Text = lvThumbnail.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[2].Text;
                txtPopulation.Text = lvThumbnail.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[3].Text;
                txtLanguage.Text = lvThumbnail.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[4].Text;
                lvThumbnail.Refresh();
            }
            }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Its almost not possible by your code.............

lvThumbnail.SelectedItems will not work the mouse hover item

Comment: but How can i Achieve that. Is that any way to selece mouse hover items